# Why doesn't GDB step into the function body?

Tags: c++, gdb

```
int filterplugin::init(StructModelConfigNode &modelConfig)
{
  
    configdir = modelConfig.dir;
    initTrieHandle(m_adWordsHandle, 0);
    string wordsFile = configdir + "/word.txt";
    if (!loadAdWords(wordsFile.c_str()))
        m_adWordsHandle = 0;
     ...
}
```

When I use  gdb to debug the code above, gdb skips the line:

```
initTrieHandle(m_adWordsHandle, 0);
```

And I found that `initTrieHandle` is defined in another c++ header file: "myTrie.h"

```
typedef void* TRIEHANDLE;
int initTrieHandle(TRIEHANDLE &handle,const char *dicPath = 0);
```

However, in the whole project, I can't find the implementation of the function `initTrieHandle()`. There are a bunch of other function definitions in myTrie.h, but there is no myTrie.cpp or myTrie.hpp. I can't find any implementation details. And probably because of that, I can't debug into this function, the GDB simply skip the line as described earlier:

```
initTrieHandle(m_adWordsHandle, 0);
```

Why is that and how to find the implementation code of that function? This is a project written by others.

Comment: "*I can't find the implementation of the function 'initTrieHandle()'*". Are you linking in any libraries that provide that implementation?

Comment: If it was written by others you might have only a non-debug-able (well, very hard to debug, at any rate) library and no source code.

Comment: @kaylum How to find whether 'linking any libraries' that provide the implementation? It is a project totally written by others. I was just trying to understand.

Comment: For starters, tell us how you are building it. Where to look for  the link libs is specific to the build system (Makefile, cmake, Visual Studio, etc). Also, is there a build log that shows the commands being run?

Comment: I checked the Makefile under build, it's a CMAKE generated file.

Comment: You need to look for `-l` options in the Makefile(s). It's difficult to say precisely where to look as there are many ways to write the Makefiles. But the bottom line is you probably have a precompiled library with debugging info stripped. So you won't be able to step into those unless you can get the maintainer to give you source code and the debug enabled library.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you. I will look into it.